# Instagram API Likes on Media does not have pagination

Tags: api, pagination, instagram, instagram-api, social-media-like

I am trying to return all the users who have liked a specific post in Instagram, but it seems to be only returning 120 of the users who have liked the image.

https://instagram.com/p/73rVHrnFqS/

There is no pagination object being returned by the query.  I don't see any limits mentioned in the documentation:

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/

I was able to reproduce it using the Instagram API Console here:

[Link to Instagram Query](https://apigee.com/console/instagram?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22get_media_likes%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22media-id%22%3A%221078521203135371922%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D)

Is it a permissions issue with users hiding their likes from the API, or does the API limit the number of likes returned.

Answer (score 3):

I can see here [Get a list of users who have liked specific media on Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013658/get-a-list-of-users-who-have-liked-specific-media-on-instagram) that someone answered that the limit is 120 from the API - which matches with my data.

That said, I am unable to find the documentation link for this 120 limit anywhere - Bonus points for anyone who can find that!

Answer (score 1):

You can you Unofficial Instagram API to get a max of 1000 likers list via calling to instagram.com/media_id/likers by attaching proper headers in post-call.

You would be able to achieve top 1000 likers of media.