# Getting media likes returning likes sorted by user ID not by recency

Tags: instagram-api

We have an application that reads media likes to perform an action if specific users like a post. A few days ago, our team noticed that the likes being returned by Instagram are sorted by the user ID that liked the post, **not** by recency. Instagram's website doesn't specify a sort order, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050603/203925) claims their sorted in descending order based on timestamp.

My question is, is this an Instagram bug, or intended behavior for the Instagram API?

Comment: interesting, just noticed it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to somehow get in touch with Instagram's developer support, and they confirmed that sorting by user ID is the intended behavior, and that they currently have no plans to change the sorting in the future.

Comment: Are the results only sorted by user ID after grabbing the recent 100 likes or are the results returning the first 100 likes after sorting the entire list by user ID?

I would suspect it's the former. It can be confirmed by comparing the likes returned from the /media/media-id/likes endpoint at various times. I'm working on confirming this now.

Comment: It's sorting by ID and then returning the likes.

Comment: Actually, the endpoint first grabs the 100 or so recent likes and then sorts them by user ID. I liked a post yesterday. Saw it in the list of likes from /media/{media-id}/likes. Then I checked the list again hours later (the post had gotten 200 more likes by this point), and my like was gone. I then unliked and reliked that post. When I hit that endpoint again, my like was in the list.